# Differentiation first principles for cube

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of function $f(x) = \sqrt{x} + \dfrac{1}{x^3}$ from the first principles.

I tried to use the formula
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.
$$

I try to expand for the $x^3$ first but it looks more and more complicated. The answer end up with $0$.

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt x + \frac{1}{x^3}$ or $\sqrt{x + \frac{1}{x^3}}$?

Comment: @Yvonne: I edited to add [mathematical formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex), and made a "reasonable guess" about your function, given your goal of computing the derivative from the Newton quotient. If the new wording does not match your intent, please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** (I'm assuming you mean $\require{cancel}f(x) = \sqrt{x} + \frac1{x^3}$.) Here's the "hard" computation for a few similar functions. You can see the pattern: in the end, there is a factor of $h$ in the numerator which will cancel with the $h$ that you are going to use as the denominator in the difference quotient, and all but the first term of the remaining factor will vanish as $h\to 0$.

For $f(x) = \frac1x$:
$$\tfrac1{(x+h)}-\tfrac1{x} = \tfrac x{x(x+h)}-\tfrac{x+h}{x(x+h)}=\tfrac{\cancel{x}-(\cancel{x}+h)}{x(x+h)} = \tfrac{-h}{x(x+h)}$$

For $f(x)=\frac1{x^2}$:
$$\tfrac1{(x+h)^2}-\tfrac1{x^2} = \tfrac {x^2}{x^2(x+h)^2}-\tfrac{(x+h)^2}{x^2(x+h)^2}=\tfrac{\cancel{x^2}-(\cancel{x^2}+2hx + h^2)}{x^2(x+h)^2}=\tfrac{-2xh - h^2}{x^2(x+h)^2}=\tfrac{-h(2x + h)}{x^2(x+h)^2}$$

For $f(x) = \frac1{x^3}$ (which is what you are using):
$$\tfrac1{(x+h)^3}-\tfrac1{x^3} = \tfrac {x^3}{x^3(x+h)^3}-\tfrac{(x+h)^3}{x^3(x+h)^3}=\tfrac{\cancel{x^3}-(\cancel{x^3}+3hx^2 + 3h^2x + h^3)}{x^3(x+h)^3}=\tfrac{-3hx^2 - 3h^2x - h^3}{x^3(x+h)^3}=\tfrac{-h(3x^2 + 2hx + h^2)}{x^3(x+h)^3}$$

I presume you can handle the $\sqrt{x}$ term without difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

And for $\sqrt$, there is the standard conjugating approach:

$\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}
=(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})\frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}
=\frac{(x+h)-x}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}
=\frac{h}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}
\to \frac{h}{\sqrt{x}}
$